# BJT small signal analysis, ignoring current sources

Tags: analog, bjt

Question for you. Currently 'm in the middle of studying for an analog II exam. I've got the following midband small signal model:

[image: Schematic]

When analyzing for midband gain, more specifically VB2/VPi1, the solution just considers the one current source (GmVpi1) to be running across the resistance RC1//Ri2.

$$\large\frac{V_{b2}}{V_{\pi1}} = -g_m \left[R_{C1} \| \left(r_{e2} + R_{E2} \| R_L \right)\left(1 + \beta_2\right) \right]$$

In reality there are two current sources! What gives? Is it because we know that the current being supplied by Gm2Vpi2 is much much smaller than Gm1Vpi1 that we ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current supplied 2nd source \$g_{m2}v_{\pi 2}\$ is not negligible and is not ignored here.

The current entering to node \$v_{b2}\$ from left is the base current to second transistor (let it be \$i_{b2}\$). Then the collector current will be \$\beta_2i_{b2}\$ hence the emitter current will be \$(\beta_2 + 1)i_{b2}\$. That is why the final equation has a multiplication term of \$(\beta_2 + 1)\$ in it.

OR the 2nd source provides a current of \$\beta_2i_{b2}\$.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, obviously in the case of this transistor the first base/emitter node is grounded and thus no base reflection occurs. Thanks!
-------------------------------------

Interesting, as base reflection still applies in other cases when that current source is not present. Why is this? (e.g. with the first transistor base/emitter node, the current source goes straight to ground, yet base reflection still applies).